# PyQt5. Как назначить "closeEvent" на "QPushButton"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Я хочу назначить кастомный метод "closeEvent" на "QPushButton", но после вызова (`button.clicked.connect(self.close)`) происходит ошибка, что переменная "event" является булевым значением: `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ignore'`.

Вот код:

```py
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Quit", "Are you sure you want to quit?", 
                QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
```

Как мне это можно реализовать?

Comment: Ответ @gil9red абсолютно верный и это означает, что вам надо заменить строку `button.clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)`  на   строку `button.clicked.connect(self.close)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closeEvent` -- это метод-событие, его лучше не вызывать вручную.

Используйте метод [close()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close):

```
button.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

---

Полный работающий пример:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        button = QPushButton('Close')
        button.clicked.connect(self.close)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Quit", "Are you sure you want to quit?",
                QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Простите, забыл указать, что я так и делал. После вызова появляется ошибка.

Comment: @jcommander, не, вы фигню говорите, т.к. судя по вашей ошибке у вас до сих пор `closeEvent` вызывается на клик, об этом говорит ошибка -- `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ignore'`, т.е. у вашего булевого объекта вызывается атрибут `ignore`, а у вас это переменная `event`. И так выходит что сигнал `clicked` у кнопок передает булевый флаг, который обозначает состояние `checked` у нее. Посмотрите мой пример в ответе